# print filename if several matches are present in file

Tags: grep

I want to print the filename if only ALL the matches are present... on different lines

```
grep -l -w '10B\|01A\|gencode'  */$a*filename.vcf
```

this prints out the filename, but not only if ALL three matches are present.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider to try `awk`? `awk` may solve it in following method,

```
awk '/10B/&&/01A/&&/gencode/{print FILENAME}' */$a*filename.vcf
```

Answer (score 0):

try following, just edited your solution a bit.

```
grep -l '10B.*01A.*gencode' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

With `grep` and its `-P` [(Perl-Compatibility)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) option and [positive lookahead regex `(?=(regex))`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), to match patterns if in any order.

```sh
grep -lwP '(?=.*?10B)(?=.*?01A)(?=.*?gencode)' /path/to/infile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -l 'pattern1' files ... | xargs grep -l 'pattern2' | xargs grep -l 'pattern3'
```

From the grep manual:

> -l, --files-with-matches
>
> Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed.  The scanning will stop on the first match.  (-l is specified by POSIX.)